# How to turn it into a Promise?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I have this ajax call and I need to turn it into a promise.

```
function myRest(url, method, callback){
    return $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : method,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(results){
            //things to do in case of success
                    },
        error: function (){
          //things to do in case of error           
}
    });
}
```

How could I also use the .then() method in case of success?
Thanks

Comment: You don't have to *turn* anything into a promise. the `$.ajax()` that you are returning already *is* a promise. Just use `.then(…, …)` on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I have this ajax call and I need to turn it into a promise.

`$.ajax()` already returns a promise.  You can just use `.then()` on it already, return the promise and get rid of the callback.  You don't need to "turn anything into a promise".  It already is a promise.  You can use that existing promise like this:

```
function myRest(url, method) {
    return $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : method,
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

myRest(...).then(function(results) {
    // success
}, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // error
});
```